# Как удалить ненужные символы

Tags: excel

Есть ячейка в Экселе с текстом.

```
Граница СЗЗ ПАО "ММК" и зона влияния на жилую застройку г.Магнитогорска,19,Граница единой СЗЗ ЛПУ г. Магнитогорска, правый берег реки Урал, пр.Металлургов
```

Мне нужно  как-то убрать `19,`чтобы стало вот так. Между двумя запятыми может быть любое количество символов.

```
Граница СЗЗ ПАО "ММК" и зона влияния на жилую застройку г.Магнитогорска,Граница единой СЗЗ ЛПУ г. Магнитогорска, правый берег реки Урал, пр.Металлургов
```

Подскажите как сделать, мучаю с ПСТР, получается после первой запятой, нужно убрать любое количество символов вместе с запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Извлекаем фрагмент текста слева до первой запятой (включительно).
2. Меняем вторую запятую на любой знак, котого не может быть в тексте.
3. Извлекаем фрагмент текста от подставленного знака (999 - количество знаков с запасом)
4. Сцепляем два фрагмента.

`=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(",";A2))&ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("$";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;",";"$";2))+1;999)`

Comment: Спасибо, это прямо как то космически)

Comment: Наверное, вместо фиксированного `999` (хотя вряд ли будет мало) лучше использовать гарантированное `ДЛСТР(A2)`...

Comment: ... и я обычно в качестве "любого знака, которого не может быть в тексте", использую BELL (`=СИМВОЛ(7)`).

Comment: *лучше использовать гарантированное ДЛСТР(A2)* - да, так универсальнее и надежнее